# Rails use a method for an associations primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with a serialized value (using `store_accessor`) that contains an associated objects ID. For example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  store_accessor :settings, [:bar_id]

  belongs_to :bar, foreign_key: :bar_id, primary_key: :id
end

Foo.first.bar_id => 123
Foo.first.bar => nil
```

I know there exists a `Bar` with an ID of 123 and I can see that the query is never even made - I'm assuming this is because Rails incorrectly thinks that `bar_id` is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Rails 4.2.10

#### Update #1

```
Foo.find(1).bar_id
Foo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> "123"

Foo.find(1).bar
Foo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> nil

Bar.find Foo.find(1).bar_id
Foo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Bar Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 123]]
=> #<Bar id: 123>
```

Comment: In `rails console`, can you reply with the sql query when you do `Foo.first.bar` and `Bar.find(123)`. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because of how both attributes are stored in the model. If you reference [how the `belongs_to` association is setup](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/723b526158df576f673c1bc28439744378a03f5d/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb#L89), it uses an attribute on the model. The store on a model defines a [`_read_store_attribute`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/723b526158df576f673c1bc28439744378a03f5d/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L127) which is different from `_read_attribute`.

If these two are different, which they are, the `belongs_to` association on a model would not be setup.

In your case, it's looking for `bar_id` as an attribute in the model; not a virtual attribute.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you think of any reason why overriding the `read_attribute` method to read the store attrs would cause problems?